# Reduction problem to another problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

I would like to show that a problem $A$ is $NP\text{-complete}$. So, I am trying to reduce 3-SAT problem to $A$. Reduction is kind of function, let say $f$. What is necessary complexity of $f$? Probably, it has be in $NP$. But, does it mean that $f$ must be a non-deterministic Turing machine working in polynomial time?

Comment: There must be a non-deterministic poly-time reduction. However, I don't know about reductions that use non-determinism.

Comment: @rus9384 I think you are wrong

Comment: @Carol; 1) search for reduction and complete on this site. 2) $P$ isnt a good name for a problem in this context because $P$ is also used for the complexity class $P$.

Comment: @miracle173, why am I wrong? Every poly-time deterministic reduction is also poly-time non-deterministic reduction. Reversal is true iff $\mathsf{P = NP}$.

Comment: @rus9384 What is a nondeterministic reduction?

Comment: @Ariel, a reduction that can be done by NTM. Of course, Karp reduction (and Turing reduction) also is such a reduction.

Comment: $f$ is called a reduction from $A$ to $B$ iff $x\in A\iff f(x)\in B$. The righthand side becomes meaningless when $f$ is specified by a NTM, what is $f(x)$?

Comment: Hint: look at the definition of NP-completeness. It's all there.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $f$ need not be a NDTM.  To prove a problem is NP-complete by reducing another NP-complete problem to it requires only a Karp reduction, which is a polynomial-time deterministic reduction.  So $f$ would live in the complexity class [FP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp).